# Is it possible to save MediaStream in react Hooks (useState)?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I am woking on WebRTC.
I have declared a variable localStream like

```
var localStream;
```

outside the component. The localStream contains the MediaStream at first but when my callback function is called after calling the Signaling Server, the variable localStream is empty. I want to store the MediaStream in the state so that it won't be empty after calling the Signaling server.

1. on page load -> localStream contains the stream
2. From client I place a call and it calls Signaling Server
3. From Signalling Server it calls back the client and here localStream is empty.

I tried useState(), useState(undefined) It doesn't work. It is null.

```
    import ....
const hubUrl = 'https://f1d3e599fe6c.ngrok.io/ConnectionHub';
const conn =
    new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl(hubUrl, signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

var localStream;
var peerConnectionConfig = { iceServers: [{ url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] };

onst webrtcConstraints = { audio: true, video: true };
const Chat = (props) => {
    
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
...
}


      receivedSdpSignal = (connection, partnerClientId, sdp) => {
        console.log('WebRTC: processing sdp signal');
        console.log('sdp', sdp);
        connection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp)).then(() => {
            console.log('WebRTC: set Remote Description');
            if (connection.remoteDescription.type == "offer") {
                console.log('WebRTC: remote Description type offer');
                console.log('localStream', localStream);
                connection.addStream(localStream);
                console.log('WebRTC: added stream');
                connection.createAnswer().then((desc) => {
                    console.log('WebRTC: create Answer...');
                    console.log('WebRTC: Description...');
                    console.log(desc);
                    connection.setLocalDescription(desc).then(() => {
                        console.log('WebRTC: set Local Description...');
                        console.log(connection.localDescription);
                        this.sendHubSignal(JSON.stringify({ "sdp": connection.localDescription }), partnerClientId);
                    }).catch(err => console.log("WebRTC: Error while setting local description", err));
                }, err => console.log("WebRTC: Error while creating the answer", err));
            } else if (connection.remoteDescription.type == "answer") {
                console.log('WebRTC: remote Description type answer');
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log("WebRTC: Error while setting remote description", err));
        }

 const initializeUserMedia = () => {
        console.log('WebRTC: called initializeUserMedia: ');
        mediaDevices.getUserMedia(webrtcConstraints).then((stream) => {
          console.log("WebRTC: got media stream");
          localStream = stream;
          let audioTracks = localStream.getAudioTracks();
          if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
              console.log(`Using Audio device: ${audioTracks[0].label}`);
              
          }
        }).catch(err => console.log("Error getting user media stream.", err));
      }
```

This function is outside UseEffect(){}. The localStream is null here.

Comment: define "doesn't work", and show your codes.

Comment: Doesn't work - It is null.

Comment: It's hard to tell the issue from the code provided, you've to add your entire file, where you're setting media stream in localStream variable and where it's getting null.

Comment: I hope you have some idea now. I added some code. @AbhaySehgal